error message: UNKNOWN_FETCH_FAILURE error when adding a filter onto sheet in Quicksight
i am facing an error message: "UNKNOWN FETCH FAILURE: Unable to fetch filter values. Refresh later or use the "Custom filter list". Appreciate your advice someone on how to fix my calculations. thanks!
I have a calculated field, this is to calculate total number of students who will be attending classes starting in the next 12 months.
I have used ifelse statement because i wanted to convert NULL value to 0 in the table visual (with 0 value, i can apply conditional formatting in table.)
    ifelse(
    isNull(

sumIf({students},
    truncDate('DD',{xEnd date})>truncDate('DD',now()) AND
    truncDate('DD',{xEnd date})<=addDateTime(12,'MM',truncDate('DD',now())))
            ),0,

sumIf({students},
    truncDate('DD',{xEnd date})>truncDate('DD',now()) AND
    truncDate('DD',{xEnd date})<=addDateTime(12,'MM',truncDate('DD',now())))


referencing the above, i created a 2nd calculated field, to group the number of student count. For example,

    ifelse(
{students_count_next_12M}< 100,'Less than 100',
'100 and above')

When i try to add 2nd field's filter into the sheet, i get the error message mentioned above.
In addition, the 2nd field cannot be added under "Group By" field wells even though the values are text. it can only be added to "Value" field wells.
what i tried to do (above).
i would like to know what can i do to correct the calculations, so that I can eventually pull the 2nd field as a filter on the sheet in Quicksight.
